# Is it possible to concat two columns in Ksqldb in CREATE STREAM statement?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I want to concat two columns and use it as a timestamp field, and I have to write it in a **`CREATE STREAM`** statement because I want to use that timestamp for calculating WINDOW TUMBLING.

The SQL code:

```sql
create STREAM testStream (Price INT,concat(cast(RlcDate as varchar),LPAD(CAST(RlcTime AS VARCHAR),8,'0')) as timestamp, Id VARCHAR) WITH (kafka_topic='testTopic', partitions=1,value_format='JSON', timestamp = 'timestamp', timestamp_format = 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSS');
```

when I run this code, it returns the following error:

```
Caused by: line 1:42: mismatched input '(' expecting {'STRING', 'EMIT',
        'CHANGES', 'FINAL', 'ESCAPE', 'INTEGER', 'DATE', 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP',
        'INTERVAL', 'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR', 'MINUTE', 'SECOND', 'ZONE',
        'PARTITION', 'STRUCT', 'EXPLAIN', 'ANALYZE', 'TYPE', 'TYPES', 'SHOW', 'TABLES',
        'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'PARTITIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'FUNCTION', 'ARRAY', 'MAP',
        'SET', 'RESET', 'SESSION', 'DECIMAL', 'KEY', 'SINK', 'SOURCE', 'PRIMARY',
        'REPLACE', 'ASSERT', 'ADD', 'ALTER', 'IF', IDENTIFIER, DIGIT_IDENTIFIER,
        QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER, VARIABLE}
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException
```

I want to know, is it correct to write **`CONCAT`** and **`CAST`** when creating a **`stream`**, or we just can use these kinds of queries in the **`select`** statement?

If it's not possible, is there any solution for solving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATE STREAM` statements define how a stream looks in terms of fields, data types, and constraints. It is not the right place to define calculation logic, i.e. *how* the fields should be filled. The right place to do this is in a `SELECT` statement, as you correctly assumed.

Try to first define your stream based on what is in your Kafka topic:

```sql
CREATE STREAM testStream (Price INT, RlcDate VARCHAR, RlcTime VARCHAR, Id VARCHAR) 
WITH (kafka_topic='testTopic', partitions=1,value_format='JSON');
```

This stream is an alternative, queriable representation of your existing Kafka topic.
Now you can select data according to your criteria and continuously expose the results of that query into a new stream (which in turn needs a backing Kafka topic):

```sql
CREATE STREAM testStreamResult WITH (kafka_topic='testTopicResult', partitions=1, value_format='JSON', timestamp = 'concat_timestamp', timestamp_format = 'yyyyMMddHHmmssSS')
AS SELECT 
`Price`,
`RlcDate`,
`RlcTime`,
concat(`RlcDate`, LPAD(RlcTime, 8, '0')) `concat_timestamp`,
`Id`
FROM testStream
EMIT CHANGES;
```

If the provided logic is correct based on incoming data, `testStreamResult` should allow you to use it in a `JOIN` with the timestamp semantics you are looking for.